# how to get out of my game while game ending conditions are not met?

Tags: python

this is my first attempt at python coding, or any coding for that matter.
I have made this simple little game, and it seems to be running fine but I want to add another option to it.

the code generate a random character with HP, attack power, XP and level, then generates a dragon with HP and attack power, the game then decides each time who strikes, and if the player wins he gets to get some Xp and level up, if the dragon wins the player is dead and it asks you to play again.

what I want to add is what if I'm in the middle of a fight, and don't want to continue, I want ask the user if they want to continue fighting, if not the game ends.

I've tried to do that but I failed.
Also , if there is anything I can do to enhance my code.

thanks in advance.

```
import random

def charGen():
    char = [random.randint(1,10),random.randint(1,3), 0, 0]#[hp, power,xp,level]
    return char
def drgnGen():
    drgn = [random.randint(1,5),random.randint(1,5)]
    return drgn
def playAgain():
    print('do you want to play again?(y)es or no')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


def xpValues(levels):
    for i in range(levels):
        n=0
        n=((i+2)**2)
        xpLevels.append(n)


def xpIncrement(XP,xpLevels,char):
    #returns the level of the character( the bracket in which the character XP level lies within) 
    #level = char[3]
    for i in range(len(xpLevels)):
        if XP>= xpLevels[i] and XP<xpLevels[i+1]:
            #level = i+1
            return i

def levelUp(char,level):
     if level+1>char[3]:
         char[0] += 1
         char[3] += 1
         print ('you are now at level %s!, your health now is %s points'%((level+1),char[0]))




def isNotDead(char):
    if char[0]>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    XP = 5 #the default XP gain after battle win
    char = charGen() #generate the character

    xpLevels=[]
    xpValues(15)
    print (xpLevels)
    print ('______________________________________')
    print ('Welcome to the Battle of the dragons!')
    print ("you are a fierce Warrior with %s health points and A power of %s points" %(char[0],char[1]))
    print ('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    while isNotDead(char):
        print(' ')
        print ('While adventuring you have met a scary looking dragon')
        print('Without hesitation you jump to fight it off!')
        print('=============================================')
        print(' ')
        drgn = drgnGen() #generate a dragon
        while True:


            roll = random.randint(0,1)
            if roll == 0:
               print("the dragon hits you for %s points" %drgn[1])
               char[0] = char[0] - drgn[1]
               if isNotDead(char) :
                   print("you have %s health left!" %char[0])
                   input('Press Enter to continue')
                   print(' ')
               else:
                    print("you're dead!Game Over")
                    print(' ')
                    break


            else:
                print("you hit the dragon for %s points"%char[1])
                drgn[0] = drgn[0] - char[1]

                if drgn[0] >0:
                    print("the dragon have %s health left!" %drgn[0])
                    input('Press Enter to continue')
                    print(' ')
                else:
                    char[2]+= XP
                    print("Horaay!you have killed the dragon!and your experience points are now %s"%char[2])
                    levelUp(char,(xpIncrement(char[2],xpLevels,char)))                    
                    input('Press Enter to continue')
                    break


    if not playAgain():
        break
```

Comment: Which is the function which handles a fight?

Comment: there is none, I just subtract the attacker power off the defender's health and repeat.

Comment: So, when do you want the message to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix to get what you want is to have a couple of flags marking whether the user is fighting or not. Also you can delay printing output until the end of the innermost loop, to avoid having to repeat too much `print`ing:

```
new_dragon = True
while new_dragon:
    print(' ')
    print ('While adventuring you have met a scary looking dragon')
    print('Without hesitation you jump to fight it off!')
    print('=============================================')
    print(' ')
    drgn = drgnGen() #generate a dragon
    fighting = True
    while fighting:
        message = []
        roll = random.randint(0,1)
        if roll == 0:
           message.append("the dragon hits you for %s points" %drgn[1])
           char[0] = char[0] - drgn[1]
           if isNotDead(char) :
               message.append("you have %s health left!" %char[0])
           else:
               message.append("you're dead!Game Over")
               fighting = False
               new_dragon = False
        else:
            message.append("you hit the dragon for %s points"%char[1])
            drgn[0] = drgn[0] - char[1]

            if drgn[0] >0:
                message.append("the dragon have %s health left!" %drgn[0])
            else:
                char[2]+= XP
                message.append("Horaay!you have killed the dragon!and your experience points are now %s"%char[2])
                levelUp(char,(xpIncrement(char[2],xpLevels,char)))                    
                continue_flag = False
        for m in message:
            print (m)
        print ('')
        if fighting:
            r = input("Press enter to continue or enter q to quit")
            if r is 'q':
                fighting = False
```

To improve the code more generally:

- make a Character class and classes for Player and Dragon that inherit shared properties from the Character class
- the check for whether to level up can be greatly simplified by just comparing whether new_xp > xpLevels[previous_xp]
- the programme will soon get over-complicated if you continue to expand it just using nested while loops. What you want is a single while loop, functions (or a class) for each stage/status of the game, variables that record the game's current status (e.g. any dragons present), and a condition that decides what to do next.
- give things clear descriptive names, using classes, e.g. player.power instead of char[2]

E.g. the following...

```
import random

class Character:
    def __init__(self, max_hp, max_power):
        self.hp = random.randint(1, max_hp)
        self.power = random.randint(1, max_power)
    def is_dead(self):
        return self.hp <= 0
    def hit_by(self, enemy):
        self.hp -= enemy.power

class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self, max_hp=10, max_power=3)
        self.xp = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.xp_thresholds = [(i + 2) ** 2 for i in range(15)]
    def battle_win(self):
        self.xp += battle_win_xp
        if self.level < len(self.xp_thresholds) and self.xp > self.xp_thresholds[self.level + 1]:
            self.level_up()
    def level_up(self):
        self.hp += 1
        self.level += 1
        print('you are now at level %s!, your health now is %s points' % (self.level + 1, self.hp))

def begin():
    game.player = Player()
    print('______________________________________')
    print('Welcome to the Battle of the dragons!')
    print("you are a fierce Warrior with %s health points and A power of %s points" %(game.player.hp, game.player.power))
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
def new_dragon():
    print('While adventuring you have met a scary looking dragon')
    print('Without hesitation you jump to fight it off!')
    print('=============================================')
    game.dragon = Character(5, 5)
def fight():
    player, dragon = game.player, game.dragon
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        player.hit_by(dragon)
        print("the dragon hits you for %s points" % dragon.power)
        if player.is_dead():
            print("you're dead! Game over")
            return
        else:
            print("you have %s health left!" % player.hp)
    else:
        dragon.hit_by(player)
        print("you hit the dragon for %s points" % player.power)
        if dragon.is_dead():
            print("Horaay!you have killed the dragon!and your experience points are now %s"%player.xp)
            player.battle_win()
            game.dragon = None
            return
        else:
            print ("the dragon have %s health left!" %dragon.hp)
    print "Press enter to continue (q to quit)"
    if input() is 'q':
        game.finished = True
def play_again():
    print 'do you want to play again?(y)es or no'
    if input().lower().startswith('y'):
        game.__init__()
    else:
        game.finished = True
battle_win_xp = 5 #the default XP gain after battle win
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dragon = None
        self.player = None
        self.finished = False
game = Game()
while not game.finished:
    if not game.player:
        begin()
    elif game.player.is_dead():
        play_again()
    elif not game.dragon:
        new_dragon()
    else:
        fight()
```

Comment: that was a great answer stuart, unfortunately I still don't know how to manage classes in python, I know the jest of it, but still needs to study it officially.but other stuff were very helpful as well, not only you answered my question but you have been a great help in the code overall, thank you very much.I'd give you a thumbs up if I can :)

Comment: I'm starting to work on your improvements, want to ask a quick question..why should I avoid a lot of printing? is it a bad thing?

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful... feel free to 'accept' and/or upvote it. About printing, no, I just meant to avoid repetitively printing the same things. If your game expands then it might be helpful to separate the printing from the rest of the game logic, for instance by putting all the printing in a class or set of functions so you could just call e.g. `print_new_dragon_message()`